# AVAssetDownloadTask not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I am having issues with downloading and playing an HLS URL at the same time.

I have followed  WWDC'16 video and also below [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MediaPlaybackGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/HTTPLiveStreaming/HTTPLiveStreaming.html).

But either I am able to play the audio or I am only able to download it. I am not able to achieve doing both the tasks at the same time.
And the download is also working only on iOS 11 beta releases, not on iOS 10 devices.

Am I missing something or there is some other way of achieving it?

Comment: format update and spellings mistake

Comment: if i remember correctly its not possible to play downloaded files in prior iOS 11 versions. Many people doing a workaround by configuring a HLS setup with a locally build in httpd on the device, so that the device delivers the media file locally.

Comment: that's what @thorb65, apple provided AVAssetDownloadTask to download HLS content from iOS 10, but it is not working for me as of now and hence the question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

There are [a lot of changes](https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2017/504op4c3001w2f222/504/504_advances_in_http_live_streaming.pdf) related to HLS and FPS for iOS 11

And there are two examples from Apple for developers:

- [FairPlay Streaming Server SDK beta](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/WWDC_2017/FairPlay_Streaming_Server_SDK_v4.0_beta/FairPlay_Streaming_Server_SDK_v4.0_Beta_1.zip) - only for XCode 9
- [FairPlay Streaming Server SDK](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/FairPlay_Streaming_Server_SDK_v3.1/FairPlay_Streaming_Server_SDK_v3.1.zip) - for XCode 8

As for me: on iOS 10 I can play and download HLS+FPS without any issues, but the same code for iOS 11 is not working (as I wrote - there a lot of new instances and workflows in it).

Comment: So have you been able to achieve it through AVAssetDownloadTask? without Fairplay?

An example piece of code to do this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @VikasDadheech You better download a sample from Apple (the links I added above) and see the part of code what you need

Comment: I did download it and checked it before posting the question here. But the problems that I was facing, were still there even after following similar set of steps. The only change being that the sample was written in Swift and I am using objective C;